# MySQL query is slow to run. Help optimize it

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

I have this query that runs quite well but is getting very slow as the entries increase in the db. Can someone help to optimize it?

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM tbl1 t1 
LEFT JOIN tbl2 t2 on t1.id = t2.tbl1_id AND t2.my_id ='5' 
WHERE t2.tbl1_id IS NULL AND
      t1.userid !='5' AND
      t1.base <= 95 AND
      t1.aloc > 0 AND
      t1.cred > 0 AND
      t1.pause < 1 AND
      t1.admin_se < 1
ORDER by t1.cred+0 DESC 
limit 20");
```

code to create table 1

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl1` (
 `id` int(30) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `msg` tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `userid` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `_date` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `base` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `cred` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `aloc` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `_expire` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `expire_date` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `_count` int(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `pause` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `src_` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `original_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `short_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `short_url_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `scheduler` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `admin_se` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `autoloadval` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `lng` int(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `rinterval` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `rcat` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '5',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11151 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Code to create tbl2

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl2` (
 `tbl2id` int(30) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `my_id` int(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `tbl1_msg_id` int(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `_date` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `_type` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `fol` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `pr_id` int(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `msg_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `tracking_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `val_optimizer` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`tbl2id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=147014 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Kindly consider that I'm new to mysql. I don't understand most of the technical terms.

### I just want to get this script to run fast. thanks

Why I did "order by t1.cred+0" I have values in the cred field from 0 to 9999. I want to list from the biggest but interestingly, 5 is listed before 10. don't know how to deal with it

Comment: As with any "help optimize mysql query", post the output of `EXPLAIN` before asking for help.

Comment: How slow is "very slow"? What performance do you require/expect? What indexes are set up on these two tables?

Comment: Like @N.B. said, post output of EXPLAIN <your query>. Also include output of SHOW CREATE TABLE t1 and SHOW CREATE tbl2. 

Why are there quotes around 5 ('5')? If this is integer data, don't quote it, you might make it impossible for MySQL to use an index on those columns (if it exists). Also, why do you order on t1.cred+0, instead of simply t1.cred ? this again may make it impossible for MySQL to use an index to support the order by operation.

Answer (score 3):

Have you added indexes to `t1.id` and `t2.tbl1_id` and `t1.cred+0`?

Comment: rogchap, I sincerely don't understand that as I'm newbie. Kindly check the query to create both tables as I have added

Comment: Adding indexes is the answer.  Why ask a question if you don't want to know the answer??

Answer (score 1):

Try to add some index on your keys. (`t1.id` and `t2.tbl1_id`) and on `group by` field aswell (`t1.cred+0`)

Using b-tree, for example, is a good idea.

[Read something about indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: @N.B. r-tree are used for create indexes for multidimensional spaces so I suppose that b-tree - in that case - are the best choice. But I have no such experience about r-tree for say that they can't be used here.

Comment: So how does one swap between different data structures? Your answer implies you can freely choose various data structures to hold indexes.

Comment: @N.B. My answer only say that b-tree(s) in that case is a good choice. Isn't it?

Comment: You can't choose what type of data structure MySQL will use when creating indexes with `INDEX` keyword. Suggesting that one should specifically use b-tree is not really much of an advice. You didn't mention what columns should be indexed or why. Throwing a statement such as "Using b-tree, for example, is a good idea" isn't really heplful, is it? Seeing we have b-tree or hash indexes (and hash ones in specific circumstances only) makes your answer not really useful. That was the point of my comment.

Comment: @N.B. No, wait. I just suggest to him to use "some index on YOUR KEYS" so my answer was complete. After editing, i just explained it. For b-tree part of answer you're partially right: he can't choose it directly (I don't use MySql so I can't know if you can chose what method use for indexing) but i still think that my answer drive him to the correct solution. If you don't think, ok: i'll respect your point of view.

Comment: thanks you people for the replies. I'm still new to stackoverflow. Still trying to find my way

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite it using exists:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1 t1
WHERE t1.userid !='5'
  AND t1.base <= 95
  AND t1.aloc > 0 
  AND t1.cred > 0
  AND t1.pause < 1    
  AND t1.admin_se < 1
  and not exists (select null from tbl2 t2 where t1.id = t2.tbl1_id AND t2.my_id ='5')
ORDER by t1.cred+0 DESC limit 20;
```

And what is the purpose t1.cred+0? This will render index on t1.cred unusable.

EDIT: indexes speed up data retrieval. In this case you will need index by cred as this is order by/limit 20 column. Use your original query (as Mark Bannister commented, join mostly performs better than exists in MySql). But make sure you lose **+0** part because sql engine will probably not be able to use index.

```
create index ix_tbl1_cred on tbl1(cred);
```

You will profit mostly by indexing equality columns, including join targets. Here is index on tbl2 column used to join tbl2 to tbl1. Now MySql will not have to read entire table2 for each row in table1 because it will check index for existance of t1.id in t2.tbl1_msg_id

```
create index ix_tbl2_tbl1_msg_id on tbl2(tbl1_msg_id);
```

This might be sufficient for this query. Other columns are not equality columns so index will have less impact. I should know your data to propose other indexes.

Comment: It should be a `not exists`, not an exists, and you need to remove the `t2.tbl1_id IS NULL` condition from the main `WHERE` clause. Also, left outer joins tend to be faster in MySQL than the equivalent exists/not exists clauses - this is the opposite of the behaviour found in many other databases (such as SQLServer). Still, it couldn't hurt to try it...

Comment: I've just edited my response. Thanks for spotting the error and for info on MySql.

Comment: You still have the `t2.tbl1_id IS NULL` condition in the main WHERE clause.

Comment: Nikola Markovinović I have used your solution but it's still slow. I think I have issue with indexing. That's what I  don't really understand in mysql. I'm still new to it. I have posted script to create both tables. Please check it and advice.

Comment: I added indexes to tables as proposed by Nikola Markovinović above and the speed issue is resolved. I think that's the solution I needed. Thanks Nikola Markovinović and thanks to all that commented and responded. I'm grateful

Comment: Why I did order by t1.cred+0? I have values in the cred field from 0 to 9999. I want to list from the biggest but interestingly, 5 is listed before 10. don't know how to deal with it

Comment: Cred is defined as varchar(30). It is not a number. Define it as int, otherwise index will not be able to sort cred as if it is a list of numbers, and your query will suffer as number of rows increase.

Answer (score 0):

Might be useful if you show us your SQL code to create the table so that we can see what you have or haven't indexed.

The slowness is not going to be caused by your SQL (usually) but on how your index your table.

Jim

Comment: I have uploaded the queries to create the two tables

Answer (score 0):

Write each column name which you want to select in your query instead of using `select * from table`.

And also create indexes and multiple column indexes to increase query performance. Read below link to know about mysql query optimization technique.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/top-20-mysql-best-practices--net-7855